# Is it normal for a computer to get slow because of processor overheating

Tags: laptop, cpu, cooling

I've red this: [Does overheating cause a computer to slow down?](https://superuser.com/questions/3371/does-overheating-cause-a-computer-to-slow-down) 
and found out that processors normally reduce their clock speed to cool themselves.
I have just converted a movie from .avi to .mp4(for psp). While it was converting the laptop is still running in perfect shape without lagging or some slow downs. Because only the browser and total video converter was open.
The conversion was done, and I shut the computer down. I turn it on again after 6 hours. And it got slow. Is it normal? Maybe, after 1-3 days without using, thats the only time that its usable again.
The hdd temp back then was 113 F. I don't know the heat released by the processor, but it is certainly hot.But the fan was still not spinning to its fullest.
Whose fault is the slow down, the processor, or the hard disk.

Details:

- Processor- 2.0 Ghz core 2 duo
- -2 Gb
- Graphics is integrated.
- Cooling pad with 3 fans
- hdd: hitachi hdd that came with the laptop(compaq b1200)

Comment: Start your computer and go directly into the BIOS. Check in your BIOS your CPU temp. Wait until temp. is stable. Is it low or too high?

Comment: is it working ok now?after 1-3 days..only time useable?,free motherbroad monitor will mointor while using-http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Info/Motherboard-Monitor.shtml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not normal.  The CPU and hard drive should cool down within minutes, if not faster, of shutting off the power.  It's entirely possible that the issue has nothing (or little) to do with the video conversion you did, but rather the result of one or more internal fans failing or starting to fail.  Another thing to check in the BIOS is fan RPM speeds.  Some BIOS will show that, some wont.  If it does, look for a fan whose RPM speed is 0 or less than a few hundred RPM.

Comment: Also, 113 F is a relatively cool temperature for a modern computer. My work laptop is a Core Duo and runs most of the time at 120-125 F even with a cooling pad.

Answer (score 1):

BBlake is correct - overheating can cause reduction of CPU lifespan, random freezes, and random resets. Eventually the CPU can burn out.

Another typical overheating scenario is the computer working correctly and then after some time it starts to malfunction.

- [This site](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/article/Maximum-CPU-Temperature/143/1) is where I read the info and will help to detect problems and show how to fix them (1st page).
- [This](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/article/142) one describes overheating avoidance.
- [This page](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/page/download_overclock) lists hardware monitors to download.

It's best to read the first page, then page 2, then download the on-screen monitor (highlighted on page 2) or "how to fix".

As for what caused the problem, you can download a [disk test from Seagate](http://www.seagate.com/www/en-us/support/downloads/seatools/) to test the drive.

The slowdown is likely to be overheating, but could be unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

trigger it again, so it goes slow, check the ram in task manager, maybe a lot is in use at the time of the slowness, or hdd space left, maybe there wasn't much left.  maybe it's the pagefile/virtual memory. and there was some change there, and a change back. windows can change it automatically sometimes.  could check cpu temp too, see if it is different, but that may be that it is working harder.. some process using it a lot - that would explain slowness, task manager would show that cpu utilization for any process.